# How to build a subset of a pandas data frame by selecting disjoint collections of columns?

Tags: python, pandas, subset

For example, say I have the following data frame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3,4,5], [6,7,8,9,10], [11,12,13,14,15]], columns=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'])
```

and I want to select columns 'a', 'c', 'd', and 'e' by column index #.
I attempted the following but it didn't work:

```
X = df.loc[:, [0, 2:5]]
```

The real data I'm working with contains several hundred variables, too many to specify by name so I'd like to use column # ranges.

Comment: I didn't see the duplicate question, although sacuL offered an additional solution that isn't in the dupe response.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `iloc`:

```
df.iloc[:, [0] + list(range(2,5))]    

    a   c   d   e
0   1   3   4   5
1   6   8   9  10
2  11  13  14  15
```

Or you can use [`np.r_`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.r_.html) to select multiple ranges:

```
df.iloc[:, pd.np.r_[0, 2:5]]
```

Comment: Ah, brilliant, thank you! I knew there was a simple solution but couldn't find the answer online.